# Express: mongodb mongoose linking entities

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a simple web app where a company sends out a question to its employees requesting for feedback. Still learning about mongodb. Been playing around with it all week & I'm slowly getting a good hang of it with some helpful assistance on the forums but only now I realize I have been using a flawed thought process to design the schema. I was initially using a user's **response** as a field in the `UserSchema` but I have now removed it (as commented out here) as I realized this is not a user's property but rather a variable  that keeps changing (yes/no/null). I now have to create a separate `AnswersSchema` (I was told I'll need one but I stubbornly argued against it - saw no sense in at the time I started the project) which I have done now (correct me if it's wrongly written/thought out). My question now is how do I modify my query in  the api to link all the three entities together on a `save` operation in the `router` `post`? **Please note** the `save` operation code shown here works but is flawed as it's for when the user has a response as one of their properties. So now only the user's name shows up on the angular front-end after I removed response on `UserSchema` which makes sense.

```
var QuestionSchema = Schema({
    id          : ObjectId,
    title       : String,
    employees   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});

var UserSchema = Schema({
    username    : String,
    //response    : String,
    questions   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}]
});  

//new schema/collection I've had to create
var AnswerSchema = Schema({
    response    : {type :String, default:null},
    question    : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'},
    employees   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswersSchema);
```

**api.js**

```
Question.findOne({ title: 'Should we buy a coffee machine?'}).exec(function(err, question) {
          //example data
          var user = new User([{
            "username": "lindelof",
            "response": "yes",
          },{
            "username": "bailly",
            "response": "no",
          },{
            "username": "suzan",
            "response": "yes",
          }]);

          question.employees = [user1._id];
          user.questions = [question._id];

          question.save(function(err) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(question);
              user1.save(function(err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
              });
          });

        });
        console.log('entry saved >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
    }
```

**UPDATE**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the right thing by adding `AnswerSchema`, as it's a many to many relationship. A question can be answered by many users (employees). A user can answer many questions. Therefore, it's good to have answer as an associative collection between the two.

[image]

With this relationship in mind, you need to change your schema a little:

```
var QuestionSchema = Schema({
    id          : ObjectId,
    title       : String,
    //employees   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});

var UserSchema = Schema({
    username    : String,
    //response    : String,
    //questions   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}]
});  

var AnswerSchema = Schema({
    response    : {type :String, default:null},
    question    : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'},
    employee   : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},  //a single employee
});
```

Now, to know if a certain user has answered a question already, just search `Answer` with his and the question's ids:

```
Answer.findOne({
        question: questionId,
        employee: userId
    })
    .exec(function(err, answer) {
        if (err) {

        } else if (!answer) {
            //the employee has not answered this question yet
        } else {
            //answered
        }
    });
```

Lastly, your submit-answer API should expect a body that contains questionId and userId (if signed in, you can get userId from session or token also). This route updates existing answer, else creates it (for create-only use `create` function)

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
            //req.body = {question: "594315b47ab6ecc30d5184f7", employee: "594315d82ee110d10d407f93", response: "yes"}
            Answer.findOneAndUpdate({
                    question: req.body.question,
                    employee: req.body.user
                },
                req.body, 
                {
                    upsert: true  //updates if present, else inserts
                }
            })
        .exec(function(err, answer) {
            //...
        });
});
```

Comment: @talwan thanks for the response again. At `Answer.findOneAndUpdate({
                    question: req.body.question,
                    employee: req.body.user` something is not happening as angular's http is not returning a response from the api side. When I do a `console.log(req.body);` just above `Answer.findOneAndUpdate` it shows me the actual body with question, name & response sent from angular. Not sure what happens after that

Comment: Also the entities get saved to the database though employee and response are null in the answer document

Comment: Where are you sending response from? Does database entry show all three fields?

Comment: If by response you mean the field 'response' for answer, I send it from angular. Yes all 3 fields are showing in the answer collection. I've updated the post with a snap shot.

Comment: my req.body in the actual values like name:"mike" and question:"Should we buy a coffee machine" as sent from angular. I see yours has the actual ObjectId's as you commented. How are the ObjectId's fetched into req.body?

Comment: when I backtrack to `Answer.findOne()`, `console.log(answer)` shows null

Comment: `router.post('/'..` requires the three fields I've mentioned. On Angular side you have the question and therefore should have the question _id as well. Similarly, you should have employee _id on Angular side. Pass these two ids and response in post call for this to work.

Comment: I totally get you now after some debugging too. I'm not sure though how to pass the question _id & employee _id to angular **post**. I do see the question _ id in angular **get**

Comment: It's best I ask this in a new post. I'll check your answer here as correct  though. Thanks

Comment: here's the issue I'm trying to sort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596959/mongodb-angularjs-how-to-post-id-from-angular-to-the-server

Comment: I managed to find question id. It was simple actually. Now I'm struggling to find user id from the token.